# Python 3.4 MatPlotLib PdfPages Value Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdfpages

I keep trying to follow the examples I see for PdfPages but keep getting the value error: No such figure: None.

```
plot1 = Chart Generating Function(argument1, argument2,...)

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('sample.pdf')
pp.savefig(plot1)
plt.close()
```

I've tried different variations of this (i.e. pdf.savefig()) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: *Please post a runnable piece of code reproducing the problem.* With what you have now, the only piece of psychic advice I can offer is to check that your `Chart Generating Function` actually returns anything.

Answer (score 2):

What solved the problem for me was removing the `plt.show()` command at the end of my chart generating function.

Answer (score 0):

I should have added more details, but somewhere in my code I had used "fig, ax = ..." when defining the figure. The "fig" part needed to be the argument in pdf.savefig(fig) in order for it to work.